# WCF Works On XP But Not Windows 7

Tags: wcf, windows-7

I have a WCF service which is hosted in a WinForms application. This WCF service calls a COM component written in ATL on Visual Studio 6. This works just fine on Windows XP. However the COM component fails on Windows 7 when calling GetFileAttributes. It says the path does not exist even though it does. It is a mapped network drive. The only reason I can think of for this is that The WinForms app which hosts the WCF service has to right clicked and Run As Administrator. I am then assuming the COM component effectively gets the same raised priveleges and therefore the mapped drive which existed under the user logged in to the machine no longer exists as far as the application is concerned.

Is this a valid assumption and if so what are my options for solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7 (and equivalents) you loose mapped drives when you run as administrator. That's because you basically switch to another login token, and the network drives are mapped only to the non-admin's.

There are a few ways to overcome this, see discussions [here](http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-general/125180-run-administrator-loses-access-mapped-drives.html) and [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/569696/accessing-unc-vs-mapped-drive-in-run-as-admin-mode-is-different).

Also, there's a registry setting (not mentioned on those links) that links the two tokens. See [KB article about EnableLinkedConnections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937624), [a discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/182758/what-does-registry-setting-enablelinkedconnections-do-on-a-technical-level) about using it.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. This is as I suspected. The solutions are not very nice and am questioning whether they are actually going to ber usable in our scenario. The last discussion I'm not going to explore simply because of the warning of it potentially making your system unsafe. But manyt thanks for the links.

Comment: @Jonnster, note that although `EnableLinkedConnections` is said to be unsafe, the reasoning is quite weak IMHO. You have the same issues without it regarding local drives, and no-one cares about that. Anyway, if this answers your question, feel free to accept it. If not, I suggest you change the tags of the question - it's more about security than it is about WCF.